# How to filter HTML table content with multiple dropdown menu options?

Tags: javascript, html-table, tablefilter

I want to filter a html table's content. Each tutorial and jsfiddle example shows only one possible filter with text input tag.

What I am looking for is a filter that works with a dropdown menu, eg. .

The user would choose an option from the dropdown and it gets filtered. I thought it is very simple, but could not figure out.

This one for example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

However it filters only one column! I want to filter in each column separately with the dropdown option menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Filter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<table id="table_format" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-list-search">
<thead>
    <tr class="content">
        <th>any
        <select id='filterText' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText()'>
            <option disabled selected>Select</option>
            <option value='filtertext'>filtertext</option>
        </select>
        </th>
</thead>
<tbody  id="myTable">
<tr class="content"><td>..multiple..<td>....
</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
function filterText()
    {  
        var rex = ""
        var rex = new RegExp($('#filterText').val());
        if(rex =="/all/"){
            clearFilter()}
        else{
            $('.content').hide();
            $('.content').filter(function() {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();
    }
    }

function clearFilter()
    {
        $('.filterText').val('');
        $('.content').show();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - so we don't have to

Comment: Also need far more detailed filtering criteria. Your expectations outlined are too vague and can be interpreted several different ways

Comment: Hi sloren. Welcome to SO! - Unfortunately you've not provided enough code for us to give a solid answer. In theory it's a simple request. In the example you cited, the code iterates over each row, but what it doesn't do is iterate over each table cell. If you supply this functionality you will filter columns. If you would like assistance please provide the foundation of what you have along with what you've tried, and we can help you further!